# Can't make GlassFish use my MessageBodyWriter in JAX-RS

Tags: json, rest, glassfish, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I need to customize JSON output from JAX-RS in GlassFish 4.0. Custom MessageBodyWriter seems like a good fit. My problem is that I can't make any examples, e.g. http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html, to be invoked by the server. I'm just setting breakpoints to see if it's hit. I know it's in the right package, etc. because I also tried custom WriterInterceptor and that one is hit just fine. I just had to put @Provider on a WriterInterceptor in the right package and that's it.

Things that I've tried so far:

1. Just use @Provider
2. Modify web.xml and use the custom application to register a custom MOXyJsonProvider. The application class is getting invoked, but MessageBodyWriter/MOXyJsonProvider is not.
3. Add META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter file with the class name inside

Here is the code:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class WebVisualizationJsonWriter extends MOXyJsonProvider {

@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return WebVisualizationJsonPayload.class == type
            || WebVisualizationJsonPayload.class == getDomainClass(genericType);
}

@Override
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return isReadable(type, genericType, annotations, mediaType);
}

@Override
protected void preReadFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, Unmarshaller unmarshaller) throws JAXBException {
    unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "$");
}

@Override
protected void preWriteTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, Marshaller marshaller)
        throws JAXBException {
    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "$");
}
}
```

None of methods above are hit whatsoever during RESTful service invocation.

Comment: From debugging, I came to the conclusion that the problem is that Jersey's `ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider` will always be picked first according to the algorithm described at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#providers-selection, unless you write a `MessageBodyWriter`/`MessageBodyReader` that is parameterized with a more specific type than `Object`. But if you do that, you cannot extend MOXy's MOXyJsonProvider anymore because that implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>.

Comment: To me, it looks like the design flaw is that `ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider` effectively makes the four methods you listed inaccessible for customizations. There should be a way to replace the default registered instance of `ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider` with a custom subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem it is necessary to disable MOXy and then enable CustomMoxyJsonProvider.

Example:

1. Create your own feature that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Feature:

   ```
   @Provider
   public class CustomMoxyFeature implements Feature {
       @Override
       public boolean configure(final FeatureContext context) {
           final String disableMoxy = CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE + '.' + context.getConfiguration().getRuntimeType().name().toLowerCase();
           context.property(disableMoxy, true);
          return true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create your own provider that extends MOXyJsonProvider:

   ```
   @Provider
   public class CustomMoxyJsonProvider extends MOXyJsonProvider {
       @Override
       public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
           return WebVisualizationJsonPayload.class == type
       || WebVisualizationJsonPayload.class == getDomainClass(genericType);
   }

       @Override
       public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
           return isReadable(type, genericType, annotations, mediaType);
   ```

   }

   ```
       @Override
       protected void preReadFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, Unmarshaller unmarshaller) throws JAXBException {
           unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "$");
       }

       @Override
       protected void preWriteTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
   MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, Marshaller marshaller)
   throws JAXBException {
           marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "$");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add this resources in Application config:

   ```
   @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
   public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

       @Override
       public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
           Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
           addRestResourceClasses(resources);
           return resources;
       }

       private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
           resources.add(com.vinichenkosa.moxyproblem.TestResource.class);
           resources.add(com.vinichenkosa.moxyproblem.custom_provider.CustomMoxyFeature.class);
           resources.add(com.vinichenkosa.moxyproblem.custom_provider.CustomMoxyJsonProvider.class);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The property name to disable the MoxyJsonFeature has changed somewhere along the path to Jersey 2.10.4, which ships with GlassFish 4.1. Instead of `jersey.config.disableMoxyJson.server`, it is now `jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson` (!), cf. [Javadoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.10/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE). So it's best to replace the code of point 1. with this: `context.property( ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true );`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue since we upgraded to Glassfish 4.1.We have also upgraded our jersey and jax-rs dependencies (listed below).Below is our custom MessageBodyWriter which is not getting invoked before writing a response to the stream

```
 @Provider
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/vnd.jenzabar.jx-json"})
public class RestDataSourceMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {

  // TODO pattern is probably too simple now, was "/paged/(^[/?]+)" 
    // and didn't work with expected URL, example "/DonationGroup/findAllGroupOriginTypes/paged/0,50"
  private static final Pattern pathPattern = Pattern.compile("/paged/(.*)");

  private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>[]> classMap;

  private static final ReadWriteLock classMapLock;

  static {
    classMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>[]>();
    classMapLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
  }


  /*
   * Instance fields.
   */


  @Context
  private volatile ServletContext servletContext;

  @Context
  private volatile HttpServletRequest request;

  @Context
  volatile Providers providers;

  @Context
  private volatile UriInfo uriInfo;

  protected volatile Logger logger;


  /*
   * Constructors.
   */


  public RestDataSourceMessageBodyWriter() {
    super();
    this.logger = this.createLogger();
    if (this.logger == null) {
      this.logger = this.defaultCreateLogger();
    }
    assert this.logger != null;
    if (this.logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
      this.logger.log(Level.FINER, "created", this);
    }
  }


  /*
   * Instance methods.
   */


  protected Logger createLogger() {
    return this.defaultCreateLogger();
  }

  private final Logger defaultCreateLogger() {
    Class<?> c = this.getClass();
    assert c != null;
    final String className = c.getName();
    String bundleName = null;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
    assert logger != null;
    if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
      logger.entering(className, "defaultCreateLogger");
    }
    while (c != null && bundleName == null) {
      bundleName = String.format("%sLogMessages", c.getName());
      if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
        logger.logp(Level.FINEST, className, "defaultCreateLogger", "Looking for a ResourceBundle with the following bundle name: {0}", bundleName);
      }
      ResourceBundle rb = null;
      try {
        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName);        
      } catch (final MissingResourceException noBundle) {
        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
          logger.logp(Level.FINEST, className, "defaultCreateLogger", "No ResourceBundle found for name " + bundleName, noBundle);
        }
        bundleName = null;
        rb = null;
      }
      c = c.getSuperclass();
    }
    if (bundleName != null) {
      logger = Logger.getLogger(className, bundleName);
      assert logger != null;
      if (logger.isLoggable(Level.CONFIG)) {
        logger.logp(Level.CONFIG, className, "defaultCreateLogger", "usingBundleName", bundleName);
      }
    }
    if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
      logger.exiting(className, "defaultCreateLogger", logger);
    }
    return logger;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isWriteable(final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType) {
      if (this.logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
          this.logger.entering(this.getClass().getName(), "isWriteable", new Object[] { type, genericType, annotations, mediaType });
      }
      boolean returnValue = false;
      if (type != null && !RestDataSourceResponse.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {

          if (annotations != null && annotations.length > 0) {
              for (final Annotation a : annotations) {
                  if (a instanceof Decorate) {
                      final DecorationType decorationType = ((Decorate)a).value();
                      if (decorationType != null && decorationType.equals(DecorationType.NONE)) {
                          if (this.logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
                              this.logger.exiting(this.getClass().getName(), "isWriteable", Boolean.FALSE);
                          }
                          return false;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          MediaType modifiedMediaType = null;
          if (mediaType.toString().equals("application/vnd.jenzabar.jx-json")) {
              modifiedMediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE;
          } else {
              modifiedMediaType = mediaType;
          }
          final MessageBodyWriter<RestDataSourceResponse> delegate = this.providers.getMessageBodyWriter(RestDataSourceResponse.class, RestDataSourceResponse.class, annotations, modifiedMediaType);
          if (this.logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
              this.logger.logp(Level.FINE, this.getClass().getName(), "isWriteable", "usingDelegate", delegate);
          }
          returnValue = delegate != null && delegate.isWriteable(RestDataSourceResponse.class, RestDataSourceResponse.class, annotations, modifiedMediaType);
      }
      if (this.logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
          this.logger.exiting(this.getClass().getName(), "isWriteable", Boolean.valueOf(returnValue));
      }
      return returnValue;
  }
```